# How do I install the riched20 and riched30 Windows packages in Wine?

Tags: winetricks

When I tried installing Riched20 and Riched30 on my system it throws this error

```
sha1sum mismatch! Rename /home/fanyam/.cache/winetricks/riched20/Q249973i.EXE

 and try again.
```

What am I supposed to do? 
I need these packages to install Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 1):

If deleting or renaming the file and trying again does not work, it may be that the file is no longer available at the location Winetricks is trying to download from.  You can check for an updated version of Winetricks at [winetricks.org](http://winetricks.org), and/or look up the location in the script and see if the file still exists at the listed location.  If not, you will need to find it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It means the file downloaded by Winetricks is corrupt or incomplete. You can simply delete the file, Winetricks will redownload it.

```
rm /home/fanyam/.cache/winetricks/riched20/Q249973i.EXE
```